# Count how many times a word is being used per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named "content"containing (a.o.) the fields "_date" and "text", for example:

```
_date      text
---------------------------------------------------------
2011-02-18 I'm afraid my car won't start tomorrow
2011-02-18 I hope I'm going to pass my exams
2011-02-18 Exams coming up - I'm not afraid :P
2011-02-19 Not a single f was given this day
2011-02-20 I still hope I passed, but I'm afraid I didn't
2011-02-20 On my way to school :)
```

I'm looking for a query to count the number of times the words "hope" and "afraid" are being used per day. In other words, the output would have to be something like:

```
_date      word   count
-----------------------
2011-02-18 hope   1
2011-02-18 afraid 2
2011-02-19 hope   0
2011-02-19 afraid 0
2011-02-20 hope   1
2011-02-20 afraid 1
```

Is there an easy way to do this or should I just write I different query per term? I now have this, but I don't know what to put instead of "?"

```
SELECT COUNT(?) FROM content WHERE text LIKE '%hope' GROUP BY _date
```

Can somebody help met with the correct query for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most easy and redable way is to make subquerys:

```
 Select 
    _date, 'hope' as word, 
    sum( case when `text` like '%hope%' then 1 else 0 end) as n
 from content
 group by _date
 UNION
 Select 
    _date, 'afraid' as word, 
    sum( case when `text` like '%afraid%' then 1 else 0 end) as n
 from content
 group by _date
```

This approach has not the best performace. If you are looking for performance you should grouping in subquery by day, also this `like` condition is a performance killer. This is a solution if you only execute the query in batch mode time by time. Explain your performance requeriments for an accurate solution.

**EDITED TO MATCH LAST OP REQUERIMENT**

Comment: good answer :) by using a join similar to my answer you can spare those UNIONs and only have to write each word once.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is almost correct:

```
SELECT _date, 'hope' AS word, COUNT(*) as count
FROM content WHERE text LIKE '%hope%' GROUP BY _date
```

use `%hope%` to match the word anywhere (not only at the end of the string). `COUNT(*)` should do what you want.

To get multiple words from a single query, use `UNION ALL`

---

Another approach is to create a sequence of words on the fly and use it as the second table in a join:

```
SELECT _date, words.word, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
   SELECT 'hope' AS word
   UNION
   SELECT 'afraid' AS word
) AS words
CROSS JOIN content
WHERE text LIKE CONCAT('%', words.word, '%')
GROUP BY _date, words.word
```

Note that it will only count a single occurrence of each word per sentence. So »I hope there is still hope« will only give you `1`, and not `2`

---

To get `0` when there are no matches, join the previous result with the dates again:

```
SELECT content._date, COALESCE(result.word, 'no match'), COALESCE(result.count, 0)
FROM content
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT _date, words.word, COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
   SELECT 'hope' AS word
   UNION
   SELECT 'afraid' AS word
) AS words
CROSS JOIN content
WHERE text LIKE CONCAT('%', words.word, '%')
GROUP BY _date, words.word ) AS result
ON content._date = result._date
```

Comment: I did not vote down your answer, but I think that this is not that the OP is asking for. Be careful, reread question.

Comment: @danihp: Where am I wrong? To me it looks like this is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: I posted comment on non edited answer, see edited time and comment time. Right now. Also, you can include `words.word` in group by clause to get a standard SQL query and enclose `text` into quotes because it is a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted, so kudos to you. However, I forgot an essential part of what I need - see the OP again. As you can see, 0n 2011-02-19, there is no mention of the word "hope". Taking your first (approach) query, is it possible to let it return a "0" value for that date? Now, the query just ignores dates on which there is no content with the word "hope"...

Comment: @Reveller: dates without matches are filtered by the WHERE. You need another join on the resultset to get other dates back.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to count all words and find the most used words (rather than looking for the count of a few specific words) you might want to try something like the following stored procedure (string splitting compliments of [this blog post](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS wordsUsed;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE wordsUsed ()
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS wordTmp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wordTmp (word VARCHAR(255));

    SET @wordCt  = 0;
    SET @tokenCt = 1;

    contentLoop: LOOP
        SET @stmt = 'INSERT INTO wordTmp SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`, " ", ?),
                                LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`, " ", ? -1)) + 1),
                                " ", "") word
                     FROM content
                     WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`, " ", ?)) != LENGTH(`text`)';
        PREPARE cmd FROM @stmt;
        EXECUTE cmd USING @tokenCt, @tokenCt, @tokenCt;
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @wordCt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE cmd;
        IF (@wordCt = 0) THEN
            LEAVE contentLoop;
        ELSE
            SET @tokenCt = @tokenCt + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    SELECT word, count(*) usageCount FROM wordTmp GROUP BY word ORDER BY usageCount DESC;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL wordsUsed();
```

You might want to write another query (or procedure) or add some nested "REPLACE" statements to further remove punctuation from the resulting temp table of words, but this should be a good start.