# Word clouds and mysql fulltext

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, tag-cloud

I am using mysql fulltext in a web site with few 1000s of articles (much like a newspaper). I created the index using the "title" and the "body" of the article.

Now I would like to include in the site something like a word cloud, i.e. a cloud with the mostly used words. I can do it manually but... shouldn't this be something already done from the fulltext engine? Do you have any ideas? Can I access its internal tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that should be done with a fulltext engine. If you really want a word cloud, you should create two tables, one table with all of the words, and another table that mentions how many times each word has been used in an article.

That being said, it is not really something that you want to do.

It's probably better to use tags that are assigned to each article.

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9144862/2143004) helpful for doing this.